# Launch memcached on boot with cron?

Tags: linux, cron, boot, memcached

How can I launch memcached on boot?

Comment: What system / version / os??

Answer (score 1):

Why cron???

If its installed on Debian ( use rcconf ) or

```
update-rc.d memcached defaults
```

If its installed on Redhat,Fedora,Centos,Suse

```
chkconfig memcached on
```

If its installed on windows..

```
Dont Know, But suggest you install it on Linux :P
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you included cron as part of the question, I'm going to assume you are looking to do this on a UNIX or UNIXlike systems (Linux, *BSD, Solaris, etc).  Although you could be trying to do this with cygwin.

This is not the normal method of starting services but it can be done.  Running things from cron can be a way to ensure a critical service is restarted if it fails.  You will need to write a wrapper script that checks if memcached is already running then starts it if it isn't.  Then put entries in the cron.

The wrapper script will look in part like:

```
...
if ps -C memcached 2>/dev/null | grep -q memcached 2>/dev/null ; then
    MEMCAHED_RUNNING=1
then

if [ ! $MEMCACHED_RUNNING ]  ; then
    memecached $options
fi
...
```

Some enhancements that you should consider for this would be a check to ensure that memcache is not only running but returning values to key requests.  That is is a bit beyond the scope of your question.

Then call the full script from cron.  A cron entry in /etc/crontab would look like

```
*/5 * * * * user /path/to/memcached_restart_script
```

In a user cron it would look like

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/memcached_restart_script
```

Most UNIX variants support the use of startup scripts.  In SysV like systems like Solaris and Linux these are files named (servicename) stored in /etc/init.d with a link or symlink named S(nn)(servicename) in a directory like /etc/rc2.d, /etc/rc3.d, or /etc/rc5.d.  In the BSD variants the script is stored under /usr/local/etc/rc.d or similar.

RHEL variants (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, Scientific Linux, etc) can manage the scripts for you with a tool named chkconfig (chkconfig memcached on).  Debian and ubuntu have a tool named update-rc.d (update-rc.d memcached defaults)  Others have different methods.

Best Regards
Rik

Answer (score 0):

Presuming linux-ish cron (ISC cron aka vixiecron, actually),

```
@reboot /path/to/memcached/start/script
```

will start memcached once at startup.  [man 5 crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) has more details.

Comment: Very interesting... It makes sense for non daemon scripts, Why would you just not use standard init start?

Comment: ...because you can do this as an unprivileged user.